# How to create an appropriate license agreement for your own Software? (Mac AppStore)

Tags: licensing, mac-app-store

**Background**:
This question caused me some sleepless nights over the last month. I'm an independent software developer and have recently finished the work on my first application. I've read a lot of articles about license agreements but I still don't know how to tackle this task in an appropriate way. My application handles user files. In every method I check for consistency & errors and I've betatested it on several systems for more than 6 months. I'm very sure nothing should go wrong, but I want to be on the save side.

---

1. Are license agreements by themselves protected by a copyright or can
   I just take one and replace the companies name? (*All of them look pretty similar to my untrained eyes*)
2. If I'm allowed to use one, am I allowed to edit it?

   I don't want my users to be "kept in a cage". **I want them to be as free as they could be.** For example I want them to be able to freely install my software on all their personal devices.
3. Where can I find non-Opensource licenses*? I've been searching for a
   long time now. I found [this Page](http://opensource.org/licenses/category) but it actually confused me more than it helped.
4. I plan on publishing my app on the Mac-AppStore. Are there licenses
   I can't use there?

   (As I mentioned above I want a "User License" model that allows the user to install it on all of his Macs)

---

If you've got any kind of experience with this topic, feel free to share your insights. It's well appreciated!

*Edit: By "non-Opensource licenses" I mean licenses for commercial applications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

## 1.

You are free to take an existing agreement you find and adapt it to your ends.  There is no originality of expression in a licensing agreement itself that would be covered under copyright law preventing your use of its language -- assuming the language fits your circumstances. You should always understand what you're agreeing to. :-)

P.S. Authority: I've worked with large law firms for 20 years as a software developer, licensing my software to them and also consulting with some of them when they had to write contracts for their own clients and didn't undertand the technical issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! - But could you back me up with some source on this? I'm sorry, but I've seen companies getting a lawsuit for using rounded corners... I feel overwhelmed by this topic. (Thanks for your edit. ;) )

Comment: P.P.S Your question about the Mac AppStore would probably be better directed directly to their legal department.

Comment: Works are copyrightable only to the extent that they are an original expression.  Legal agreements contain "boilerplate" -- standard language that is the very opposite of original expression.

Comment: I have also written software licensing agreements which the lawyers for the other side thought had been written by an attorney. If you read a gazillion of these agreements, and understand what the provisions mean, you can see that it would extremely difficult for anyone to come up with any new truly original expression of a provision that would leave you open to a copyright infringement suit for reusing it. Not that it's impossible, but you have a better chance of winning Powerball lottery than being sued for adapting standard licensing terms found in another contract.

Comment: That was exactly what I thought. But I feel that licensing has nothing to do with common sense. ;)

Comment: http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/